Spring Boot microservices with JWT (Cannot run Integration test (401 Unauthorized Error))
I try to implement an example of Spring Boot microservices with JWT. I have some problem. I cannot run all integration tests of product service even if I defined bearer token in terms of admin and user for its relevant endpoints. I got 401 Authorized error for all tests. How can I fix it?
Here is the repo : Link
Here is the security config of product service.
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    @EnableMethodSecurity
    public class SecurityConfig {
    
        private final UserServiceClient userServiceClient;
    
        @Bean
        protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
            return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
        }
    
        @Bean
        public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(
                final HttpSecurity httpSecurity,
                final CustomBearerTokenAuthenticationFilter customBearerTokenAuthenticationFilter,
                final CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint customAuthenticationEntryPoint
        ) throws Exception {
    
            httpSecurity
                    .exceptionHandling(customizer -> customizer.authenticationEntryPoint(customAuthenticationEntryPoint))
                    .cors(customizer -> customizer.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()))
                    .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                    .authorizeHttpRequests(customizer -> customizer
                            .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    )
                    .sessionManagement(customizer -> customizer.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                    .addFilterBefore(customBearerTokenAuthenticationFilter, BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.class);
    
            return httpSecurity.build();
        }
    
        private CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
            CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
            configuration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("*"));
            configuration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("*"));
            configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*"));
            UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
            source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
            return source;
        }
    
        @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }
    }

Here is the test method of integration test
    @Test
        void givenProductPagingRequest_whenGetProductsFromAdmin_thenReturnCustomPageProduct() throws Exception {
    
            // Given
            ProductPagingRequest pagingRequest = ProductPagingRequest.builder()
                    .pagination(
                            CustomPaging.builder()
                                    .pageSize(1)
                                    .pageNumber(1)
                                    .build()
                    ).build();
    
            String productId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    
            ProductEntity expected = ProductEntity.builder()
                    .id(productId)
                    .name("Test Product")
                    .unitPrice(BigDecimal.valueOf(12))
                    .amount(BigDecimal.valueOf(5))
                    .build();
    
            List<ProductEntity> productEntities = new ArrayList<>();
            productEntities.addAll(Collections.singletonList(expected));
    
            Page<ProductEntity> productEntityPage = new PageImpl<>(productEntities, PageRequest.of(1, 1), productEntities.size());
    
            List<Product> productDomainModels = productEntities.stream()
                    .map(entity -> new Product(entity.getId(), entity.getName(), entity.getAmount(),entity.getUnitPrice()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
    
            CustomPage<Product> productPage = CustomPage.of(productDomainModels, productEntityPage);
    
            // When
            when(productReadService.getProducts(any(ProductPagingRequest.class))).thenReturn(productPage);
    
            // Then
            mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/api/v1/products")
                            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                            .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(pagingRequest))
                            .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + mockAdminToken.getAccessToken()))
                    .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
                    .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
                    .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.httpStatus").value("OK"))
                    .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.isSuccess").value(true))
                    .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.response.content[0].id").value(expected.getId()))
                    .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.response.content[0].name").value(expected.getName()))
                    .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.response.content[0].amount").value(expected.getAmount()))
                    .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.response.content[0].unitPrice").value(expected.getUnitPrice()));
    
            // Verify
            verify(productReadService, times(1)).getProducts(any(ProductPagingRequest.class));
    
        }

Here is CustomBearerTokenAuthenticationFilter shown below
@Slf4j
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomBearerTokenAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final UserServiceClient userServiceClient;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(@NonNull final HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                                    @NonNull final HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                                    @NonNull final FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        log.debug("API Request was secured with Security!");

        final String authorizationHeader = httpServletRequest.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);

        if (Token.isBearerToken(authorizationHeader)) {
            final String jwt = Token.getJwt(authorizationHeader);
            userServiceClient.validateToken(jwt);
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
    }
}


Here is the screenshot of any test result shown below
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /api/v1/products
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json;charset=UTF-8", Authorization:"Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJCZWFyZXIiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJqdGkiOiJmOGM3M2JhNy0zNDU2LTQ4NDgtOTFiYy1iN2E3OWM2M2E5ODciLCJpc3MiOiJJU1NVRVIiLCJpYXQiOjE3MjExNjE5MjYsImV4cCI6MTcyMTE2MzcyNiwidXNlclN0YXR1cyI6IkFDVElWRSIsInVzZXJMYXN0TmFtZSI6IkRvZSIsInVzZXJQaG9uZU51bWJlciI6IjEyMzQ1Njc4OTAxMDExIiwidXNlckVtYWlsIjoidXNlcmFkbWluQGV4YW1wbGUuY29tIiwidXNlclR5cGUiOiJVU0VSIiwidXNlckZpcnN0TmFtZSI6IkpvaG4iLCJ1c2VySWQiOiJjZTJkOGI2Yi0wZGVlLTRlNGYtODdjOS05ZTRkY2Y4ZDI5OGUifQ.SH5mUFw59Ux2HX6VCIeIifslZFx1RQSTzT1R_zgNbWX1K5vngoAkzFP4kjrOUgS8tqJnBuzY98t5bCZA74L0vuZkNibDdI7Pc8HwHL3k2H2x6vtGPIC0sEJOVWPiNu7Lgb0XF77xp0_KEKw_UkIwfgYY-CCKL-fcAKBwf4z5QY26rtgXxrHn8Ajmh9DCpya9_LnEcplLfcxRWFWmkN2IL8OsklO5EtSSRo14uaKb7ZE4J3lV57ZJG1ADmYfDFO_nJBNFmwSpaUa1VM_6AB1vOTiv4OliVhbA6PQzrQ7xeIGlaAinrV1AoZfOQIFO-rkkkwYd2D91ymTCVEpBrk60Cg", Content-Length:"44"]
             Body = {"pagination":{"pageNumber":0,"pageSize":1}}
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = null

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 401
    Error message = null
          Headers = [Vary:"Origin", "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers", Content-Type:"application/json", X-Content-Type-Options:"nosniff", X-XSS-Protection:"0", Cache-Control:"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate", Pragma:"no-cache", Expires:"0", X-Frame-Options:"DENY"]
     Content type = application/json
             Body = {"time":"2024-07-16T23:32:07.4830196","httpStatus":"UNAUTHORIZED","header":"AUTH ERROR","isSuccess":false}
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<401>
Expected :200
Actual   :401


don't post links to your repo, instead include all the relevant code in the question - in this case your controller 1. method you are try to read, 2. the test code 3. security configuration

@JAsgarov I just shared it.

so from what I understand mockAdminToken.getAccessToken() provides you with token that is supposed to get you authenticated in CustomBearerTokenAuthenticationFilter. Debug your custom filter to see why you mock access token doesn't work.

@JAsgarov I debugged it. When userServiceClient.validateToken(jwt); is called in CustomBearerTokenAuthenticationFilter , it throws the error. What's why I got 401. How can I fix it?

to be able to answer that i would need to see 1) CustomBearerTokenAuthenticationFilter code 2) error with stacktrace

@JAsgarov I already shared the error. I also shared CustomBearerTokenAuthenticationFilter

without stacktrace I can't tell which line throws an error. If I have to guess, I am going to guess that mockAdminToken.getAccessToken() doesn't create a valid JWT token, and therefore tokenService.verifyAndValidate(jwt); throws an error. BUT this is just a guess - it could be anything therefore you need to debug it.

@JAsgarov Here is the line throwing the error : https://github.com/Rapter1990/springbootmicroserviceswithsecurity/blob/main/apigateway/src/main/java/com/springbootmicroservices/apigateway/filter/JwtAuthenticationFilter.java#L56

don't post links to your repo, instead include all the relevant code in the question (the method that throws an error)

@JAsgarov I already shared the relevant code userServiceClient.validateToken(jwt); . It throws the issue when it enters the filter.

not a single code snippet that you have provided contains code userServiceClient.validateToken. Anyways, to wrap this up your probem is you are making an http request to validate your token, which requires your authServer to validate it. Since authServer wasn't the one which issued the mock token, it doesn't surprise me that it rejects it. I don't understand however why you don't feel comfortable debugging your own application - it would be much faster and less mistake prone than me making guesses based on limited info you have provided. In any case best of luck :)

Print the exact value of mockAdminToken.getAccessToken() and test it at jwt.io. It may be expired or not signed correctly.

@JAsgarov I can get jwt token from final String jwt = Token.getJwt(authorizationHeader); in CustomBearerTokenAuthenticationFilter but userServiceClient.validateToken throws the issue through feign client in my opinion. How can I fix it?

@JohnWilliams The token is already valid.

Please add the token text to the question and log its value in CustomBearerTokenAuthenticationFilter just before it gets validated. Add this logging output for the test (fails) and non-test call (succeeds) to the question.
